# How to open Windows PowerShell as admin with Python using pynput

Tags: python, powershell, keyboard, key, pynput

I'm trying to write a script in Python that opens Windows PowerShell using pynput.
My program is going to open PowerShell and write inside PowerShell.

This is what I got so far:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 
import time
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
time.sleep(0.3)

keyboard.type("powershell") 

keyboard.press(Key.ctrl) # This opens the script with a UAC request.
keyboard.press(Key.shift) #
keyboard.press(Key.enter) #
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl) #
keyboard.release(Key.shift) #
keyboard.release(Key.enter) #

time.sleep(0.5)
keyboard.press(Key.left) 

time.sleep(0.3)

keyboard.release(Key.left)

time.sleep(0.3)

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

I try to keep it organized.

I can't understand why, but my program stops after "time.sleep(0.5)" on line 18.

Thanks for taking the time to respond, Regards, Samuel

Comment: Assuming that's what you're doing: You fundamentally can't automate responding to the UAC dialog. Its very point is to require a conscious decision by a _human_.

Comment: I understand. I will find a way around the UAC, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't allow in allowing keystroke during user control prompt if done with a software.
Rubber ducky is used for that purpose.

Comment: Hi, your answer lacks details. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer accordingly.